# changing UIWebView frame on device rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, landscape, autorotate

I'm developing an app that is locked to portrait mode. However one view is acting as a full screen 'player' for various media types.

I'm using a `UIView` subclass that has a `UIWebview` subview to play the media.
This is presented full screen on top of the viewing stack. My problem arises in making only this view rotate for landscape content - e.g. videos & pdfs.

To do the rotation I'm setting an observer in the init method:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(deviceRotated:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

and rotating as so:

```
- (void)deviceRotated:(NSNotification *)notification {
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[notification object] orientation];
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6f delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{ [self.webView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0)]; }
                     completion:nil];
    } 
    else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6f delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{ [self.webView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / -2.0)]; }
                     completion:nil];
    } 
    else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6f delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{ [self.webView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI)]; }
                     completion:nil];
    } 
    else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6f delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{ [self.webView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0)]; }
                     completion:nil];
    }
}
```

I know I need to alter the frame size for `self.webView` when rotating, but I am getting strange results.

I've tried setting to container view as a large 'square' with length `[[UIScreen mainscreen] bounds].size.height` and placing the web view in the middle, but it moves about inconsistantly - it seems as if the width & height values are getting set from the dimensons before the rotation.

I've also tried setting `autoResizingMask` flexible height & width, but as the container view is off the screen this stretches the web view offscreen also.

Comment: code reduction: only change a float value in the if statements, and use it afterwards. Try using bounds, although apple likes to not change the names of width and height even when you're rotated, it's very annoying.